# I am trying to make my social items responsive but it is not working how to fix it any suggestions plz

Tags: html, css

```
https://faizan-ul-hasnain.github.io/Resume-Project-/
This is my github file plz check this how to fix it
```

https://faizan-ul-hasnain.github.io/Resume-Project-/

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use media query for mobile width and do this for below class.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .group_3 {
             flex-direction : column;
             align-items: unset
    }
}
```

Below will be the result.

[image]

Comment: i will try this code as soon as possible

Answer (score -2):

Change the display flex to display block might work for you

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 535px) {
.group_3 {
    display: block;//change flex to block
}
//you can give some margin to the socials from top for
good looking
.group_3 .socials {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
}
```

Comment: it is fine but i want my icons section in infront of contact section

Comment: display block property makes my social icons section in the next line but in large device i want to make it infront of contact section how to do this

Comment: Use media query for small devices with a screen size below 535px.
It will work fine for small devices now
I have updated the CSS please check

Comment: not it is not working